# BackboneJS issue with posting/saving model

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have a modal window which has date displayed, which on click opens an inline date picker, where the user can select a new date

```
$(document).on("click",".editableDateTxt", function () {
    var currElmModelId = $(this).attr('data-model-id');
    var currElmModelAttr = $(this).attr('data-model-attr');
    var input = $('<input />', {'type': 'text', 'data-model-id': currElmModelId, 'data-model-attr': currElmModelAttr, 'class':'datePicker', 'value': $(this).html()});
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    parent.append(input);
    $(this).remove();
    input
    .datepicker({
        onSelect: function(date) {
            var divEle = $('<div />', {'class': 'editableDateTxt','data-model-attr':currElmModelAttr,'data-model-id':currElmModelId,'html':date});
            parent.append(divEle);
            self.model.get("myCollection").get(currElmModelId).set(currElmModelAttr, date);
            $(this).remove();
        }
    }).focus();
});
```

On select of any date, the picker is closed and the selected date is set in my model attribute.

**Now when I save the model, it saves it correctly first time (i.e. passes the selected date in the model)....But when I open the modal again, select a new date and save again, it saves the earlier/old date**...even though the statement for

```
self.model.get("myCollection").get(currElmModelId).set(currElmModelAttr, date);
```

is executed and the new date gets set in the model

```
self.model.save({},{
    success: function() {
        self.removeModal();
    }
});
```

Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: Can you clarify, why you append an input to the event triggering element and then remove the element with `$(this).remove();` ? It looks like your input is lost and has no DOM attached to it after you remove the whole parent.

Comment: So I do remove because I replace the div with input and vice-versa (to show inline-edit)...But even though I do remove, I set the attributes data-model-id/data-model-attr to the other element (div/input) and also set the model attribute)...so the issue is why do I not get the model attribute value when I do save ? There is no other place in the code where I am modifying the model attr